# Axapta 2012 Import xpo, table already exists

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

I created a table in prod and now trying import it to dev but when importing it throws an error. "A table, Extended Data Type, Base Enum or class called ..... already exists. Import of Table aborted." However the table doesn't exist in neither AOT nor SQL.

I know I shouldn't have created the table in Prod first but I needed a fast soluiton.

Anyways I restarted dev service and synchronised data dictionary in AOT but it didn't work. What else I should do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution. After deleting cahce files (.AUC) in directory 
C:\Users[USERNAME]\AppData\Local and restarting client import worked.